# JS / JSTree syntax confusion with array's

Tags: javascript, jstree

Ok, I can write code in Delphi and PHP.  This JS has me all confused.

What I'm trying to do is, using jstree, display which nodes are selected on the web page and pass a CSV to a form variable.

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="event_result">&nbsp;</div>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="evtstotal" id="evtstotal">
</form>
```

I have this js code and it works perfect.  It updates the event_result when I select a jstree node and passes the CSV to the evtstotal when I submit the form:

```
 function (e, data) {
    var z, i, j, r = [];
    for(i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
         if (data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).id > 0) {
              r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).id);
         }
    }
    $('#event_result').html('Selected:<br /> ' + r.join(', '));
    var element = document.getElementById("evtstotal");
    element.value = r.join(', ');
})
```

What I'm looking to do is display the text value of the selected nodes on the page and pass the id value of the selected nodes to the form.

if I change the r array to this, it still works and passes the text instead:

```
  r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text);
```

However, if I try to push two array's, it doesn't work:

```
 function (e, data) {
    var z, i, j, r = [];
    for(i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
         if (data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).id > 0) {
              r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).id);
              z.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text);
         }
    }
    $('#event_result').html('Selected:<br /> ' + z.join(', '));
    var element = document.getElementById("evtstotal");
    element.value = r.join(', ');
```

I tried this and it works if I try to push to just one array, but not both.

```
 var data = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]);
 r.push(data.id);
 z.push(data.text);
```

I'm guessing I somehow have the syntax wrong or I just don't understand the logic behind js.  Chrome is telling me: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the full script section... working:

```
<script>
$('#evts')
    .on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
        var z, i, j, r = [];
        for(i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
            if (data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).id > 0)
            {
                r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).id);
            }
        }
        $('#event_result').html('Selected:<br /> ' + r.join(', '));
        var element = document.getElementById("evtstotal");
        element.value = r.join(', ');
    })
.jstree({
    'core' : {
        'multiple' : true,
        'data' : 
            [
                <?php echo json_encode($catarray) ?>
            ]
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you initialize `z`? Looks like `r` is initialized to a new empty array, but not `z`.

Comment: Not a JS programmer. I suspected that's the problem but not sure how to initialize it?  Doesn't adding it to the var statement do that?

Comment: Adding it to the `var` statement *declares* the variable, but it doesn't initialize it. See how `r` is initialized with `r = []`? Do the same thing for `z`:

Comment: `var z = [], i, j, r = [];`

Comment: Thanks Pointy!  I didn't realize that the r= [ ] was initializing an array. I'm more familiar with the php r=array().  Works perfect now!